# How to permit Rack::Test::UploadedFile with strong parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, strong-parameters

I'm using strong_parameters gem with Rails 3.2. To test an image upload process, I have an incoming post request with parameters:

```
{"photo"=>{"image"=>#<Rack::Test::UploadedFile:0x000000069ce1f8 @content_type="image/png", @original_filename="test.png", @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/test.png20130420-9529-1xuka4v-1>>, "status"=>"approved", "in_use"=>false}, "controller"=>"member/photos", "action"=>"create"}
```

How can I permit the image attribute for assignment? I tried;

```
params.require(:photo).permit(:image)
```

but it doesn't work and says `Validation failed: Image can't be blank`.

When I permit all parameters with `params.require(:photo).permit!` it works fine.

Comment: did you find a solution ? stuck with this, too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html

> PERMITTED_SCALAR_TYPES    =   [ String, Symbol, NilClass, Numeric,
>   TrueClass, FalseClass, Date, Time, StringIO, IO,
>   ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile, **Rack::Test::UploadedFile**]

So you just need to permit it as a scalar type:

```
params.require(:photo).permit(:image)
```

Just tested on `Rails 4.1.1`

Comment: Seems like the problem fixed with Rails 4.1.1.

Comment: That was fixed like a year ago in `4.0.0` https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/9357

Comment: I re-examined the problem recently so I'm not sure when it was fixed. Tho I think when I faced with this problem Rails 4.0 was still new.